# Symfony Components - Routing

Tags: php, routes, url-routing, symfony

## Question:

### Seriously, I'm using it well? It works but I'm not sure about correct way of using Symfony Components. Anybody use these components like me?

1. I'm not sure about exception handling in dispatch()
2. I'm not sure about using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in code below too...

My **composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/routing": "^3.2"
    }
}
```

My **index.php**

```
<?php

include './vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Christopher {
    public $context;
    public $routes;

    public function __construct() {
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $this->context = $context->fromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals());
        $this->routes = new RouteCollection();
    }

    public function route($methods, $path, $controller) {
        $this->routes->add($path, new Route(
            $path,
            [
                '_controller' => $controller
            ],
            [
                'id' => '[0-9]'
            ],
            [],
            '',
            [],
            $methods
        ));
    }

    public function dispatch() {
        $matcher = new UrlMatcher($this->routes, $this->context);

        try {
            $matcher = $matcher->match($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

            call_user_func_array($matcher['_controller'], array_slice($matcher, 1, -1));
        } catch (MethodNotAllowedException $e) {
            echo 'Route method is not allowed.';
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
            echo 'Route does not exist.';
        }
    }
}

$christopher = new Christopher();

$christopher->route('GET', '/posters', function () {
    echo '<a href="/posters/1">1. Poster</a>';
});

$christopher->route('GET', '/posters/{id}', function ($id) {
    echo 'ID - ' . $id;
});

$christopher->dispatch();
```